# FirebaseUI not working for apple IOS and macOS devices in some region while working for others

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have a web application that uses firebase UI to sign user in. We have already replaced the auth domain in firebase config to the custom domain where the app is running and have also tried switching to signInWithPopup but the social providers Facebook and Microsoft do not seem to work on certain iOS and macOS devices while working for those in others. While sign in with Google works for everyone.

Like in my application I am able to login comfortably with Microsoft via firebase UI in India, but on the same iOS version I am unable to do so in USA. Where it gets more bizarre is on macOS I am able to log in to application via Facebook in India and Ukraine but not in USA. This might not be related to regions but to specific devices. But for me since all the devices are essentially the same I don't seem to figure out the issue. Also I have verified and the settings of browsers on all the different devices is same.
`<script type="module">
const authorization = firebase.auth();

```
const uiConfig = {
    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult : function(authResult, redirectUrl)
        {   
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
            return false;   
        },
        uiShown: function() 
        {
            document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        }
    },
    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        'microsoft.com',
        firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
};
   
// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(authorization);

// The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
```

</script>`

This is my code snippet, that I am using to render firebase UI. For the devices on which it is not working what actually happening is:

1. The page loads
2. User selects sign in with Microsoft
3. User is taken to Microsoft page (either by redirection or by popup, does not matter in our case)
4. User completes the sign in on Microsoft page
5. User is taken back to our page but now the login ui disappears and the loader is not visible

I also checked the user in not signed in by looking at firebase user record in local storage.

Note: For other devices(where it is working) on coming back to login page it tries to extract the login token of user and if it gets it, it is added as the cookie and the application works as expected.

`firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => { if (user) { user.getIdToken().then(function (accessToken) { document.cookie = @Json.Serialize(FirebaseAuthConfiguration.CookieName) + "=" + accessToken.toString() + "; path=/"; }); } });`

---

Devices its working fine on:

Windows Machines

Android Devices

IPhones in India

Devices its having issues on:

IPhone, IPad (Microsoft and Facebook not working USA and Ukraine`your text`)

Macbook(Facebook not working Ukraine)

Macbook (Facebook and Microsoft not working USA and Ukranine

Tried replacing the auth domain in firebase config to the custom domain where the app is running also switching to signInWithPopup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution, safari does not allow sub domain of a site to access its internal storage, which in turn affects all the web browsers running on iOS since they all use webkit. Opting for firebase hosting did not help in my case either, the only possible solution I found was to either Self-host the sign-in helper code in my domain or to Proxy auth requests to firebaseapp.com. The issue lies here with cross domain storage access. In my opinion and my findings [Proxy auth requests to firebaseapp.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#proxy-requests) appears to be the only fruitful way to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. After hours of searching, I can confirm this is the only thing that worked for me.